# Sort from Largest to Smallest

Tags: vba

I need to sort the table from Largest to Smallest as column Q.

codes gives no errors but doesnt work as well. It firstly filters well and sorts with no success:

```
introws = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$q$" & introws).AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">4", Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("$A$1:$q$" & introws).Sort Key1:=Range("q:q"), Order1:=xlDescending
Range("q:q").Sort (xlDescending)
```

Both lines dont work, it just stays unsorted....
How to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort a range value with `filter`, you need to apply specific method in a sequence, it involve `clear sortfields` > `add key` > `sort.apply`, the following is a simple sort for the range with data filter:

```
With Sheet1
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
    .AutoFilter.Sort.Apply
End With
```

[image]

To apply the sort method in your case, you may try to following code modication, it should be work as expected, please perform a test for both case:

```
introws = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$q$" & introws).AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">4", Operator:=xlFilterValues

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("Q1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
    .AutoFilter.Sort.Apply
End With
```